# Solidity: How to represent bytes32 as string

Tags: ethereum, solidity

This may be simple in other languages but I can't figure out how to do it in Solidity.
I have a `bytes32` like this `0x05416460deb76d57af601be17e777b93592d8d4d4a4096c57876a91c84f4a712`.

I *don't* want to convert the bytes to a string, rather I just want to represent the whole thing as a string, like "0x05416460deb76d57af601be17e777b93592d8d4d4a4096c57876a91c84f4a712".
How can this be done in Solidity?

Update:
Why I need to do this: Basically I connect to an oracle, which does some work off-chain and finally uploads a file to IPFS. I need to get the content identifier into my contract from the oracle. The oracle can only send `bytes32` as a response, so I convert it to a [multihash](https://github.com/saurfang/ipfs-multihash-on-solidity/blob/master/contracts/IPFSStorage.sol) and send only the `digest` as `bytes32` from oracle to contract.
So far so good, I can recreate the multihash in my contract. The problem is that after this I create an `ERC721` (NFT) token and I have to store some reference to the IPFS file in the metadata, which can only be in `string` format. This is where I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: There's currently no easy way, because string is also a byte array. So you'd have to write a converter, that would create a 64-length byte array (that would later be converted to string) and fill it with each value somehow transformed to the ascii value representing the byte half. Example: half-byte `0` becomes `0x30`, half-byte `5` becomes `0x35`, half-byte `d` becomes `0x64`, etc. And then you can convert this new byte array to string... What is the reason behind the converting to string? Maybe a event log would be sufficient (so that an off-chain app could convert it more easily)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated my question to include why I have to do this. This indeed seems too complex for a relatively simple task, and I can only imagine how much gas this would consume... so I'm open to alternative solutions too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While the answer from @Burt looks correct (didn't test it though), there is a much more efficient way to solve the same task:

```
function toHex16 (bytes16 data) internal pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    result = bytes32 (data) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
          (bytes32 (data) & 0x0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000000000000000000000) >> 64;
    result = result & 0xFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000 |
          (result & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF0000000000000000) >> 32;
    result = result & 0xFFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000 |
          (result & 0x0000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF00000000) >> 16;
    result = result & 0xFF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000 |
          (result & 0x00FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF0000) >> 8;
    result = (result & 0xF000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000) >> 4 |
          (result & 0x0F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F00) >> 8;
    result = bytes32 (0x3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030 +
           uint256 (result) +
           (uint256 (result) + 0x0606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606 >> 4 &
           0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) * 7);
}

function toHex (bytes32 data) public pure returns (string memory) {
    return string (abi.encodePacked ("0x", toHex16 (bytes16 (data)), toHex16 (bytes16 (data << 128))));
}
```

This code produces upper case output.  For lower case output, just change 7 to 39 in the code.

**Explanation**

The idea is to process 16 bytes at once using binary operations.

The `toHex16` function converts a sequence of 16 bytes represented as a `bytes16` value into a sequence of 32 hexadecimal digits represented as a `bytes32` value.  The `toHex` function splits a `bytes32` value into two `bytes16` chunks, converts each chunk to hexadecimal representation via the `toHex16` function, and finally concatenates the `0x` prefix with the converted chunks using `abi.encodePacked` function.

The most sophisticated part is how the `toHex16` function works.  Let's explain it sentence by sentence.

The first sentence:

```
result = bytes32 (data) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
      (bytes32 (data) & 0x0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000000000000000000000) >> 64;
```

Here we shift the last 64 bits of the input to the right by 64 bits, basically doing:

```
0123456789abcdeffedcba9876543210
\______________/\______________/
       |               |
       |               +---------------+
 ______V_______                  ______V_______
/              \                /              \
0123456789abcdef0000000000000000fedcba9876543210
```

The second sentence:

```
result = result & 0xFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000 |
      (result & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF0000000000000000) >> 32;
```

Here we shift the last 32 bits of both 64-bit chunks to the right by 32 bits:

```
0123456789abcdef0000000000000000fedcba9876543210
\______/\______/                \______/\______/
   |       |                       |       |
   |       +-------+               |       +-------+
 __V___          __V___          __V___          __V___
/      \        /      \        /      \        /      \
012345670000000089abcdef00000000fedcba980000000076543210
```

The next sentence:

```
result = result & 0xFFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000 |
      (result & 0x0000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000FFFF00000000) >> 16;
```

does:

```
012345670000000089abcdef00000000fedcba980000000076543210
\__/\__/        \__/\__/        \__/\__/        \__/\__/
 |   |           |   |           |   |           |   |
 |   +---+       |   +---+       |   +---+       |   +---+
 V_      V_      V_      V_      V_      V_      V_      V_
/  \    /  \    /  \    /  \    /  \    /  \    /  \    /  \
012300004567000089ab0000cdef0000fedc0000ba980000765400003210
```

And the next one:

```
result = result & 0xFF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000 |
      (result & 0x00FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF0000) >> 8;
```

does:

```
012300004567000089ab0000cdef0000fedc0000ba980000765400003210
\/\/    \/\/    \/\/    \/\/    \/\/    \/\/    \/\/    \/\/
| |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |
| +-+   | +-+   | +-+   | +-+   | +-+   | +-+   | +-+   | +-+
V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V   V
/\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\
01002300450067008900ab00cd00ef00fe00dc00ba00980076005400320010
```

The final sentence in this series is a bit different:

```
result = (result & 0xF000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000) >> 4 |
      (result & 0x0F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F000F00) >> 8;
```

It shifts odd nibbles to the right by 4 bits, and even nibbles by 8 bits:

```
01002300450067008900ab00cd00ef00fe00dc00ba00980076005400320010
|\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\  |\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V
000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f0f0e0d0c0b0a09080706050403020100
```

So all the nibbles of the initial data are distributed one per byte.

Now with every byte `x` we need to do the following transformation:

```
x` = x < 10 ? '0' + x : 'A' + (x - 10)
```

Let's rewrite this formula a bit:

```
x` = ('0' + x) + (x < 10 ? 0 : 'A' - '0' - 10)
x` = ('0' + x) + (x < 10 ? 0 : 1) * ('A' - '0' - 10)
```

Note, that `(x < 10 ? 0 : 1)` could be calculated as `((x + 6) >> 4)`, thus we have:

```
x` = ('0' + x) + ((x + 6) >> 4) * ('A' - '0' - 10)
x` = (0x30 + x) + ((x + 0x06) >> 4) * 7
```

The final statement:

```
result = bytes32 (0x3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030 +
       uint256 (result) +
       (uint256 (result) + 0x0606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606060606 >> 4 &
       0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) * 7);
```

Basically performs the above calculation for every byte.  The

```
0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
```

mask after the right shift is needed to zero out the bits "dropped" by the right shift in the original formula.

BTW, it would be better to ask questions like this one at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Amazing Job at explaining that. I cam confirm to everyone that this is working in Solidity v 0.8.7 . Other functions that use byte tend to fail even when you fix the deprecation error of byte --> bytes1

Comment: Such an ingenious transformation, beautiful!

Answer (score 4):

Function `bytes32ToString` turns a bytes32 to hex string

```
function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string memory) {
    uint8 i = 0;
    bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(64);
    for (i = 0; i < bytesArray.length; i++) {

        uint8 _f = uint8(_bytes32[i/2] & 0x0f);
        uint8 _l = uint8(_bytes32[i/2] >> 4);

        bytesArray[i] = toByte(_f);
        i = i + 1;
        bytesArray[i] = toByte(_l);
    }
    return string(bytesArray);
}

function toByte(uint8 _uint8) public pure returns (byte) {
    if(_uint8 < 10) {
        return byte(_uint8 + 48);
    } else {
        return byte(_uint8 + 87);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the openzeppeline library, there is Strings library which can convert uint256 to Hexstring, now you need to convert bytes32 to uint256, it is easy to do it by `uint256(bytes32Data)` function, If you need use console.log in remixd, please use `import "hardhat/console.sol";` in the beginning.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/api/utils#Strings

In the following is my testing code for your reference:

```
    function getKeccak256(string memory _text) public pure returns(bytes32) {
    // bytes32
    // example: _text = hello_world
    // result:  0x5b07e077a81ffc6b47435f65a8727bcc542bc6fc0f25a56210efb1a74b88a5ae
    bytes32 hexBytes = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_text));
    
    // uint256
    // result: 41174386367651647791915356226295557979724762511302101813587183743367440278958
    uint256 numHex = uint256(hexBytes); 
    console.log("the numHex is : ", numHex); 

    // string
    // result: "0x5b07e077a81ffc6b47435f65a8727bcc542bc6fc0f25a56210efb1a74b88a5ae"
    string memory hexString = Strings.toHexString(numHex);
    console.log("the hexString is : ", hexString); 

    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_text)); 
}
```